# ConEmu + msys2 zsh

Tags: cygwin, zsh, conemu, msys

On ConEmu page concerning the [cygwin/msys terminal connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) there are examples related to `conemu-cyg-64.exe`. I readapted them to `conemu-msys2-64` in ConEmu 171109 as follows (line breaks are for readability):

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1
 & set "PATH=C:\msys64\usr\bin\;%PATH%"
 & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-msys2-64.exe /usr/bin/zsh.exe -l -i -new_console:p
```

The problem is that `cat AnsiColors256.ans` produces lower quality results when compared to those published on ConEmu page below: [image]

Also a number of ordinary keybindings (such as "home" and "end") do not work. 
It is possible to read the key codes with the `cat` command and assign them with `bindkey` in `~/.zshrc`, e.g.:

```
bindkey "^[OH" beginning-of-line
```

I wonder if this the right path to go.

As regards ANSI colours, I have no idea of the solution.